# Parse string into array of numbes in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I've recently taken up C++ and I'm having a bit of difficulty adapting from other languages. I'm sure there's a much easier solution to this, but I can't figure out why this won't work.

Basically, I need a way to turn an input, like `5 66 193` (unknown length of integers), into a vector/something else, like "`[5, 66, 193]`".

This is my code:

```
vector<int> A;
string AToParse;
getline(cin, AToParse);
int pos = 0;
while (pos < AToParse.length()) {
    if (AToParse[pos] == ' ') {
        pos++;
        continue;
    }
    string tmp = "" + AToParse[pos];
    if (pos + 1 >= AToParse.length()) break;
    for (int i = pos + 1; i < AToParse.length(); i++) {
        if (AToParse[i] == ' ') {
            pos = i + 1;
            break;
        } else {
            tmp += AToParse[i];
        }
    }
    int tmpint = stoi(tmp);
    A.push_back(tmpint);
}
for (int Ai : A) {
    cout << Ai << endl;
}
```

Comment: I might have misread your question when I wrote my answer. If you were looking for debugging help with your code, then please add sample input/output that your code generates and/or error messages it produces to you question. In my answer I am showing you the "*much easier solution to this*".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requires `#include`s for `<sstream>` and `<iterator>`:

```
std::stringstream parseStream{AToParse};
std::vector<int> A(std::istream_iterator<int>{parseStream}, std::istream_iterator<int>{});
```

`std::stringstream` behaves the same way as `std::cin` or `std::ifstream`, only that it uses the `std::string` passed to it as input buffer. So you can use `int x; parseStream >> x;` and the like as well.

The `std::istream_iterator<int>` is a convenient iterator that keeps reading `int`s from a stream discarding whitespaces. (the same behavior as that of `parseStream >> x;` iterated)

And the `std::vector` constructor taking two argument considers the first argument an iterator to the beginning of a source range to construct the vector from and the second the end of that range.

A default-constructed `std::istream_iterator<int>` represents the end or failure of the stream input operation.

Putting this all together, the vector will be constructed by reading integer by integer from the `AToParse`, discarding whitespaces, until the end of the string is reached or an input failure happens (e.g. because the string contains characters not interpretable as integers).

---

To make the code more concise you can leave out the type for the second iterator. The iterator will be constructed from the empty brace-enclosed initializer list with the correct type, because it will be deduced be the same as the type of the first argument due to the `std::vector` constructor requiring that:

```
std::stringstream parseStream{AToParse};
std::vector<int> A(std::istream_iterator<int>{parseStream}, {});
```

---

Since C++17, you can drop the extra repetition of the type name for the `std::vector`. It will be deduced correctly from the iterators due to this new feature in C++17 called *class template argument deduction* (CTAD) and you will have to mention the type that you want to read from the string only once, in accordance with the *dont repeat yourself* rule:

```
std::stringstream parseStream{AToParse};
std::vector A(std::istream_iterator<int>{parseStream}, {});
```

Note however that this will do the expected thing only when you use parentheses for the `std::vector` initializer. It will not do the correct thing with a brace-enclosed initializer list.